# How to retrieve the serialized field name of an Elasticsearch Nest.Field

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to get the field name of a field which is created with `Infer.Field<MyDocument>(doc => doc.StringField1)`.

Example code:

```
using System;
using Nest;
using Xunit;

namespace Elasticsearch.Tests
{
    public class MyDocument
    {
        public string StringField1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SerializeField
    {

        [Fact]
        public void TestFieldName()
        {
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://myesdomain.com:9200"));
            var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

            var stringField = Infer.Field<MyDocument>(doc => doc.StringField1);
            // TODO: Code to get then name of stringField when serialized
        }
    }
}
```

Can I leaverage the client in order to serialize the name of the `stringField` as it would do in any request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better solution that uses a `Nest.FieldResolver`.

```
using System;
using Nest;
using Xunit;

namespace Elasticsearch.Tests
{
    public class MyDocument
    {
        public string StringField1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {

        [Fact]
        public void TestFieldName()
        {
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://myesdomain.com:9200"));
            var fieldResolver = new FieldResolver(connectionSettings);
            var stringField = Infer.Field<MyDocument>(doc => doc.StringField1);
            var fieldName = fieldResolver.Resolve(stringField);

            Assert.Equal("stringField1", fieldName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I found the answer myself:

Short:

```
client.SourceSerializer.Serialize(stringField, ms);
```

Complete:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Nest;
using Xunit;

namespace Elasticsearch.Tests
{
    public class MyDocument
    {
        public string StringField1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class SerializeField
    {

        [Fact]
        public void TestFieldName()
        {
            var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://myesdomain.com:9200"));
            var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

            var stringField = Infer.Field<MyDocument>(doc => doc.StringField1);
            string fieldName;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                client.SourceSerializer.Serialize(stringField, ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    fieldName = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            Assert.Equal("\"stringField1\"", fieldName);
        }
    }
}
```